# Transfer 1.7.0.2 Database to a Fresh Install of 1.8.0.0 Magento Install

Tags: magento

I want to transfer my same old websites on new upgraded server. I have magento 1.7.0.2

1.I installed new fresh copy of 1.8.0.0 on new server

2.dropped all tables of the database.

3.imported my 1.7.0.2 database.

It seems to work fine, I can't tell if there might be issues I don't seem to find at the moment? Are there new tables or columns n the 1.8.0.0 database version? Can't find information about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this in the reverse order:

1. install your 1.7 tables in a new database (disable cache before!)
2. install a fresh instance of magento 1.8 files and run the install-routine by using the 1.7 database
3. copy your media folder to 1.8
4. check if all your modules are available for 1.8 and install them

http://neoshops.de/2013/08/03/how-to-upgrade-magento-using-old-database/

Comment: We have installed magento 1.8 added the required extensions and finally updated the live site database.  We are unable to checkout.